# Historical data on Google Maps Distance Matrix API

Tags: google-distancematrix-api

Can i get travel time data from google maps distance matrix API on the past dates, such as November 2017, using driver modes ? And if it possible, how can i do it ?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to but it looks like there is a time threshold that after you just get Zero_Results response.

I tried some dates in 2017 and even 2 weeks back with no luck.

you can try yourself finding the date that you want in epoch time [1] and and fill this request with the time and your API key.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=San%20Francisco,%20CA&destinations=San%20Jose,%20CA&mode=transit&departure_time=(epoch_time)&key=(your_api_key)

[1]https://www.epochconverter.com/

Answer (score 0):

I am testing and I believe the limit for historical data is one week only for transit mode.